# Check if hash has a key that contains some text

Tags: ruby, string, hash

I want to check if a hash has a key that contains some text. It may not be the exact key, but the key must contains (like the `.include?`) the text. My solution for this is:

```
some_hash.select {|k,v| k.include? "foo"}.empty?
```

But this will generate one more hash. I just want to check the existence of the key. Is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This would be a little nicer:

```
some_hash.any? {|k, v| k.include? "foo"}
```

(To me this reads as *"does the hash have any keys which include 'foo'?"*)

Alternatively, this may <s>be less efficient, but</s> actually be a little more efficient (see comments), and perhaps a little more readable:

```
some_hash.keys.any? {|k| k.include? "foo"}
```

Comment: Your middle one doesn't work, as it assigns a key/value array to "key", and then you get Array.include?, not String.include?, which doesn't do the partial match. A quick timing check suggests that your last way, which I agree is more readable, is also slightly faster than your first way.

Comment: @glenn mcdonald: Ah! That it would be a k/v array was my first instinct, but due to a happy accident my test case worked :)  Edited, thanks/+1!

Comment: Nice clean solution +1

Comment: How would this be modified to actually fetch the key(s) that match?

Comment: @HEATH3N You could use `select` instead of `any?`.

Comment: `k` isn't necessarily a symbol.

Answer (score 5):

```
some_hash.keys.any? {|k| k.include? 'foo' }
```

Answer (score 0):

`some_hash.any? {|k,v| k.include? "foo"}`